# Using same connection for publish and subscribe to a mqtt topic with Spring Integration Java DSL

Tags: java, spring, integration, mqtt, dsl

I have the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MqttConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MqttClientProperties mqttClientProperties;

    @Autowired
    ActionHandlerManager actionHandlerManager;

    @Autowired
    private ActionDispatchManager actionDispatchManager;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("messagePackObjectMapper")
    private ObjectMapper messagePackObjectMapper;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow getMqttInFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(getMqttInBound())
                .handle(actionDispatchManager)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageProducerSupport getMqttInBound() {
        String[] allTopics = getActionHandlers().parallelStream()
                .flatMap(actionHandler -> actionHandler.getTopics().stream())
                .map(topic -> topic.replaceAll("\\{(.*?)\\}", "+"))
                .toArray(String[]::new);

        int[] allQos = getActionHandlers().parallelStream()
                .flatMap(actionHandler -> actionHandler.getQos().stream())
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .toArray();

        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter messageDrivenChannelAdapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("exhibitManager",
                getMqttClientFactory(), allTopics);

        messageDrivenChannelAdapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        messageDrivenChannelAdapter.setConverter(getMessageConverter());
        messageDrivenChannelAdapter.setQos(allQos);

        return messageDrivenChannelAdapter;
    }


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttOutBoundChannel")
    public MessageHandler getMqttOutBound() {
        MqttPahoMessageHandler mqttMessageHandler = new MqttPahoMessageHandler("exhibitManager", getMqttClientFactory());
        mqttMessageHandler.setAsync(true);
        mqttMessageHandler.setDefaultTopic("/test");

        return mqttMessageHandler;
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "mqttOutBoundChannel")
    public interface MqttGateway {
        void sendMessage(byte[] message);
    }

    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory getMqttClientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        mqttClientFactory.setServerURIs(String.format("tcp://%s:%s", mqttClientProperties.getHost(), mqttClientProperties.getPort()));
        mqttClientFactory.setWill(new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory.Will("disconnect", "test".getBytes(), 0, false));
        mqttClientFactory.setCleanSession(false);

        return mqttClientFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MqttMessageConverter getMessageConverter() {
        DefaultPahoMessageConverter messageConverter = new DefaultPahoMessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setPayloadAsBytes(true);

        return messageConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public List<ActionHandler> getActionHandlers() {
        return actionHandlerManager.getActionHandlers()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

With this configuration, the client disconnects and reconnects many times. What is the optimal configuration to connect to the topic as a publisher and subscriber with the same clientId?

Comment: does this happen only in the first couple of minutes until the app is up? if that's the case I might have a solution for you

Comment: The client disconnects when publishing a message on a topic. I think that another connection is created with the same clientId.

Comment: Multiple connection attempts with the same client ID would explain your problem. Have you changed your code to share a single mqtt connection? You seem to have at least two calls to getMqttClientFactory which every time you call it creates a new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory - that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: @blacksword another advice when using Spring use method injection instead of ivoking the method. For e.g. 
@ Bean
public IntegrationFlow getMqttInFlow(MessageProducerSupport  mqttInbound) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound)
            .handle(actionDispatchManager)
            .get();
}

Comment: that way you avoid similar situations to what barny suggested